# Is Deltaspike compatible with Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-bytecode-asm, deltaspike

According to [its doc](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html) Deltaspike Data uses ASM:

> As of DeltaSpike v1.4.0, the Data module internally leverages the Proxy module, which wraps ASM 5. No external dependencies required, and now we have full support for interceptors on partial beans.

It seems that [ASM 6](http://asm.ow2.org/history.html) has been released with Java 9 support, so it seems that Deltaspike is probably not compatible with Java 9 unleass there an update is released?

Comment: I don't know anything about Deltaspike Data but it includes ASM 5 then it is unlikely to support v53.0 class files or newer (JDK 9 has v53.0, JDK 10 has v54.0). It will likely work if you use it with v52.0 class files and older but it would be better to ask on the Deltaspike Data mailing list or issue tracker about that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been fixed in [DELTASPIKE-1351](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-1351) and is now available via [Deltaspike Data 1.9.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.deltaspike.modules/deltaspike-data-module-api/1.9.0). Deltaspike Data 1.9.0 is working for me under Java 11.